# Getting user likes and friends likes by category

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, categories

I need to get a user's music and movie likes, and a user's friends music and movie likes. Is there a way to add to the following query the category name?

https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes

https://graph.facebook.com/likes?ids=id1,id2...

I tried adding &category=Musician%2fband but that doesn't work.

Does anyone have an idea of how it can be done?

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FQL (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/)

`fql?q=SELECT page_id,type, description FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT uid, page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE uid=me()) AND type='musician/band'`

**EDIT**

Since August 17, 2016, FQL is no longer available and cannot be queried.